# Bind key which has same keycode, without losing second key

Tags: linux, keyboard

So I want to bind one of my less(<) keys as Shift as it is just above control key and it would be handy as it is just above Ctrl key. But this key has the same keycode as less which comes out when I press ','+Shift.
The shift+',' xev output:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
root 0xc4, subw 0x0, time 1185360, (-132,-64), root:(462,254),
state 0x1, keycode 59 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 94
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The '<' button xev output:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
root 0xc4, subw 0x0, time 1267856, (-247,180), root:(347,498),
state 0x0, keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Since the operating system has no means to differ between those two keys it is impossible to map them separately. Take a look at your BIOS (or EFI or whatever firmware runs the boot process) if you can switch the modifier key mapping. Afterwards you might get separate key codes.

Comment: But I have to press shift to select second less.

Comment: Might be. But apparently (according to your statement above) both sequences are mapped to the same key code by your keyboard/system.

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't have the same keycode. The former keycode is 59 and the latter is 94.

To use keycode 94 as right shift, use this xmodmap script:

```
keycode 94 = Shift_R
add shift = Shift_R
```